Unable to capture exception in task
I have a method responsible for enabling and disabling various options of a program based on access to certain databases. The system checks the connections to each one separately and makes the necessary changes in the menus. In certain situations, the checks take a few seconds, and to avoid making the user wait, the checks are performed in the background. These are the codes that are executed
First, the original call:
private async void ComprobarConexiones()
        {
            List<Task> cheks = new List<Task>();
            Task<bool> tGICO = Task.Run(() => BDManager.ChekConnectionGICO());
            Task<bool> tWIP = Task.Run(() => BDManager.ChekConnectioniMove());
            cheks.Add(tGICO);
            cheks.Add(tWIP);

            while (cheks.Count != 0)
            {
                Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(cheks);

                if (completedTask == tGICO)
                {
                    HabilitarMenusGICO(tGICO.Result);
                }
                else if (completedTask == tWIP)
                {
                    HabilitarMenusWIP(tWIP.Result);
                }
                cheks.Remove(completedTask);
            }
        }

And the logic:
    public static bool ChekConnectionGICO()
    {
        return GetInstanceGICO().ChekConnection(2);
    }


    public bool ChekConnection(int intentos = 1)
    {
        if (impersonated)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(GetCadenaConexion());
            return ImpersonationHelper.Impersonate(sb.UserID, sb.Password, () =>
            {
                return CheckConectionLogic(intentos);
            });
        }

        return CheckConectionLogic(intentos);
    }

    private bool CheckConectionLogic(int intentos = 1)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection testConexion = GetSQLConn();

            if (!PingHost(testConexion.DataSource.Split('\\')[0]))
            {
                return false;
            }

            testConexion.Open();
            if (testConexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                #region testSelect
                string testSelect = @"SELECT COUNT(*) 'Tablas'
                                    FROM sys.all_objects T
                                    WHERE T.is_ms_shipped = 0
                                    AND T.type IN ('U', 'V')";
                #endregion testSelect

                SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(testSelect, testConexion);
                SqlCommandBuilder build = new SqlCommandBuilder(adaptador);
                DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
                adaptador.Fill(dtTable);
                if (dtTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "0")
                {
                    return false;
                }

                testConexion.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                intentos--;
                if (intentos == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return CheckConectionLogic(intentos);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

            intentos--;
            if (intentos == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return CheckConectionLogic(intentos);
            }
        }
    }

The problem is that an exception occurs at the line testConexion.Open();. However, the catch block doesn't seem to capture it, and as a result, the retry counter doesn't decrease, and for some reason, the program enters into a loop.
I'm fairly sure the problem has something to do with how the process is being called via a TASK (in other parts of the program, the code is called synchronously and works fine), but I haven't been able to solve it. Any suggestions?

What exception? How did you know the exception was thrown at that line? You provided only one loop, but it doesn't seem to loop permanently.

The specific exception itself doesn't concern me. In this case, it’s a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (which is correct because I am testing with a user who lacks the appropriate access), but the code should be able to catch it and recover by returning false. However, it seems that the exception is never caught.

Wrong assumption, set breakpoints and debug. Btw, on exception you don't close connection. Perhaps using finally block is a good idea?

Set breakpoint on testConexion.Open();, hit F5 (run), when debugger stops on this line hit F10 (step over), what happens next?

When I press F5 or F10, I never reach a new line; the exception always triggers again immediately.

It may concern the problem, so please add the exception with the stacktrace to your question. And you have not told me how you know the exception was thrown. From log , msgbox or debugging?

Alright, I’ve discovered that after pressing F5 multiple times, the exception is finally caught. Many times (42, I’ve counted), the exception is thrown 42 times in a loop on the same line without progressing before being caught. I had never insisted so much with F5 and assumed it was an infinite loop. Therefore, the problem turned out not to exist. Apologies
